# PHP/CodeIgnitier Get a single value from this multimdimensionnal PHP array

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I want to retrieve a single value from this php array.
My array in PHP is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 27
            [id_customer] => 19
            [my_cart] => Array
(
    [c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 39000
            [name] => HEBERGEMENT WEB MUTUALISE PREMIUM
            [rowid] => c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
            [subtotal] => 39000
        )

    [a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 150000
            [name] => HEBERGEMENT WEB MUTUALISE ULTIMATE
            [rowid] => a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c
            [subtotal] => 150000
        )

)
1
            [created_at] => 2020-03-30
        )

)
```

The problem is that I can not get qty, name, price

I tried by doing this in my foreach

```
foreach($cart_data as $cd){
  echo 'ID Table: '.$cd->id.'<br>';
  echo 'ID customer: '.$cd->id_customer.'<br>';

  $data = $cd->my_cart;
  if(is_array($data)){
    foreach($data as $s){
      echo 'My cart: '.$s;
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing is happened! I want to get price, name and qty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When inserting into database I encode it like this `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data))` and decode in with `json_decode` while getting the $data. So now I have this:

```
foreach($cart_data as $cd){
  echo 'ID Table: '.$cd->id.'<br>';
  echo 'ID customer: '.$cd->id_customer.'<br>';
  $data = json_decode($cd->my_cart);

  foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->qty;
    echo $row->price;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get several keys from `my_cart` array, try to write the loop like this :

```php
  foreach($cart_data as $cd){
    echo 'ID Table: '.$cd->id.'<br>';
    echo 'ID customer: '.$cd->id_customer.'<br>';

    $data = $cd->my_cart;
    if(is_array($data)){
        $filtered    = [];
        $keys        = ['qty', 'name', 'price']; // the keys
        $column_keys = array_flip($keys); // getting keys as values
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            // getting only those key value pairs, which matches $column_keys
            $item = array_intersect_key($val, $column_keys);
            if (!empty($item))
                $filtered[$key] = $item;
        }
        echo 'My cart: <br/>';
        print_r($filtered);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is just displayed ID Table & ID customer

Comment: could you do `print_r($cd->my_cart)`?

Comment: yes! echo '<pre>'; print_r($cd->my_cart); echo '</pre>'; display all my_cart

Comment: what is the output of that `print_r`?

Comment: Array ( [c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c] => Array ( [id] => 2 [qty] => 1 [price] => 39000 [name] => HEBERGEMENT WEB MUTUALISE PREMIUM [rowid] => c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c [subtotal] => 39000 ) [a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c] => Array ( [id] => 4 [qty] => 1 [price] => 150000 [name] => HEBERGEMENT WEB MUTUALISE ULTIMATE [rowid] => a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c [subtotal] => 150000 ) ) 1

Comment: so the `echo 'My cart: <br/>';` line is not printed?

Comment: when I make is_array($data), I get nothing but I get 1 while making is_string($data). So I think my $data is a string

Comment: I tried to use str_split to convert it as an array, so I need help to do it

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```php
    echo 'My cart: '.$s;
```

The variable `$s` holds an array, not a string. If you follow your data structure, the contents of `$s` would be similar to this:

```
    Array (
        [id] => 4
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 150000
        [name] => HEBERGEMENT WEB MUTUALISE ULTIMATE
        [rowid] => a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c
        [subtotal] => 150000
    )
```

So, in order to get name, qty, price, you'd need to change your inner loop to something like this:

```php
foreach ($data as $s) {
    echo 'Product name: '  . $s['name'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Quantity: '  . $s['qty'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Price: '  . $s['price'] . '<br>';
}
```

What happens when you try to use an array as a string is that it shows up as the string "Array" and will trigger a `PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in [location]`. I'm guessing this error might be the reason you get nothing, instead of `My cart: Array`.

Comment: I tried it but nothing is displayed as result for $s['name'],  $s['qty'] and  $s['price']

Comment: Even when I do print_r($s), nothing is displayed

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure the data you've shown is the value of `$cart_data` right before that loop, or is there something else modifying the data?

Comment: I am sure! Coz I get the customer_id by doing $cd->id_customer

Comment: Okay, just to sanity check: do a `var_dump` of `$cart_data` _on the line before the `foreach loop`_. Then also do a `var_dump` of `$data` _on the line before` the `if(is_array($data))`_. Or better yet, step through it with a debugger if you can.

Comment: when I make is_array($data), I get nothing but I get 1 while making is_string($data). So I think my $data is a string

Comment: I tried to use str_split to convert it as an array, so I need help to do it

Comment: Okay, can you do a `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, and then post the results? This should show you the type as well as the contents, to make sure there aren't any weird things going on (for example, `$data->my_cart` could be either an array or the `print_r` of that array and you couldn't tell the difference).